# Magento 2 How load product by sku and boot the system minimally?

Tags: magento2, product, optimization, flat

Me need minimal load system that get **ONLY**: *Product Name, Product Type, Product Url, Thumbnail Url, Price, Sub products for Configurable*.

Preferably **use catalog_product_flat_ table** (i think it's good idea for optimization)

How can I do it?

Help me,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the object manager directly, inject the ProductFactory:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory)
{
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$product->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
```

or to do a full load (the above loads it using a collection):

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$product->load($product->getIdBySku($sku));
```